# Requisição HTTP GET - Jquery - Node.js

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, restful

Antes de mais nada, queria dizer que sou desenvolvedor .net, então estou meio perdido no que estou fazendo.

Se eu entendi bem, eu baixei o node.js e dentro do prompt do node.js eu dei um CD na pasta do meu projeto (onde está meu index.html e index.js), depois do cd dei um npm start, ai ele subiu como localhost:9966 e eu estou usando a pagina desde então, tudo aparentemente funcionando bem.

Mas agora estou travado em uma requisição GET/POST com AJAX, e o mais estranho, quando faço um GET para a api do VIACEP eu recebo o retorno normalmente, mas quando mando para minha api .net ele me da erro de CORS.

Segue o Código

```
function getCep(){

    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://webchatapi.azurewebsites.net/api/atendimento/solicitacoes/',
        //url: 'https://viacep.com.br/ws/09831380/json/ ',   
        headers: {'content-type': 'application/json'},
        crossDomain: true,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);    
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log("error");
        }
    });
}
```

Quando utilizo o url do VIACEP:

[image: Viacep]

Quando utilizo minha api .net

[image: Api .net]

resultado da minha api ao dar get pelo Chrome/Postman:

[image: Chrome/Postman]

Já estou preso nisso a 2 dias, não sei o que fazer, obrigado !

Comment: Relacionada: [Erro CORS com domínios diferentes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/388143/3774)

Comment: Boa tarde Icaro, eu já havia visitado esse link antes de fazer a pergunta, como pode ver no meu código já inclui "crossDomain: true" e não gostaria de mudar minha aplicação para extensão, também já tentei usar jQuery.support.cors = true, entretanto não sei como habilitar o CORS no node.js como informado "res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'); ", onde eu coloco esse código?

Comment: Coloquei o link apenas como relacionado. =D  -- Sobre sua pergunta me parece que o seu site `localhost` esta com `res.setHeader...`, porem esse erro esta sendo causado pelo site `webchatapi.azurewebsites.net` é ele quem esta recusando as requisições de outros domínios.

Comment: Eu imaginei que fosse algo com a API, mas nela eu já habilitei o Cors :(

Answer (score 0):

Consegui solucionar o problema.

Aparentemente meu servidor node.js e estavam normais, o problema estava na minha API .net que não estava habilitado o cors!

Segui essa documentação e agora tudo funciona normalmente:

[Documentação .net CORS](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api)